# Can't get Ruby strptime to work

Tags: ruby, datetime, strptime

I currently have

```
format = '%d%m%Y:%H:%M:%S'
date_time = '30/Jun/2013:07:38:27'

puts DateTime.strptime(date_time, format)
```

which returns

```
ArgumentError: invalid date
    from (irb):95:in 'strptime'
    from (irb):97
    from (irb):usr/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format string doesn't match the format you're actually using.  `%m` is the zero-padded month (`01..12`), whereas you're using `Jun`, which calls for `%b`.  You also need to put slashes in to make the format match.

This is all [documented](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html).

```
require 'date'

format = '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S'
date_time = '30/Jun/2013:07:38:27'
DateTime.strptime(date_time, format)
# => #<DateTime: 2013-06-30T07:38:27+00:00 ((2456474j,27507s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the dumb question :/

Comment: @BSpiros You're welcome! And I don't think it was a dumb question; nobody's born formatting dates, and learning takes time and walking through confusion.  I *would* say that it would be a wise first step to check the documentation first and see if you can sort it out.  That doesn't always help, but many times it does.

Comment: I went over it, but I am working with several date formats on this project so I think I just had my head too cluttered. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The `format` didn't match what you have in `date_time`. Particularly, you have slashes and abbreviated month name in `date_time`. Use this.

```
format = '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S'
```